# Go to implementation doesn't work when I right-click in VS Code on the Mac

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I'm started to develop .net on Mac. Now I have issue like on title. When I'm trying to right click for "go to implementation" It didn't show on right click menu.
Thx.

[right click menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRw4a.png)

I deleted some extensions and installed it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted C# and .net tools extension then installed again. I tried give path on settings and deleted path. Finally I just closed and reopen vscode then it works. Idk how :) I did before a lot of times.